# Replace transparent pixels (alpha) with black in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an image with alpha channel indicating what the background is.

How do I de-alpha-y (remove the alpha channel) and make the background pure black with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic syntax would be

```
ffmpeg -i in.png -filter_complex "color=black,format=rgb24[c];[c][0]scale2ref[c][i];[c][i]overlay=format=auto:shortest=1,setsar=1" out.png
```

What this does is generate a black canvas and resizes it to the image size. Then the image is overlaid on top. The opaque pixels from the image are retained but the transparent pixels reveal the canvas underneath.

Comment: Thanks! But `[overlay @ 0x2f4c660] [Eval @ 0x7ffd03a272e0] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'auto'
[overlay @ 0x2f4c660] Unable to parse option value "auto"
[overlay @ 0x2f4c660] [Eval @ 0x7ffd03a27360] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'auto'
[overlay @ 0x2f4c660] Unable to parse option value "auto"
[overlay @ 0x2f4c660] Error setting option format to value auto.
[Parsed_overlay_3 @ 0x2f4c5a0] Error applying options to the filter.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x2f48560] Error initializing filter 'overlay' with args 'format=auto:shortest=1'
Error initializing complex filters.`

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg to 3.4 or newer.

Comment: This is amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Installing ImageMagick and running magick FILE -alpha off FILE works nice and quick and straightforward too.  It's another program, but leaves ffmpeg to what it's better at.